# "Righting wrongs" or "Writing wrongs"?

Tags: idioms

I've seen people using different forms of this phrase.

- "Righting some wrongs", "Righting the wrongs", "Right a wrong"
- "Writing some wrongs", "Writing the wrongs", "Write a wrong"

It seems to be an idiom that probably means that mistakes are brought into the open to be fixed, but that's not the core aspect of this question.

**Question:**

For this idiom, is it proper to use the term "right", "write", or either?

**Some thoughts:**

*Right* - Maybe correcting a misdoing is an attempt to fix it or to make it *right*.

*Write* - Maybe correcting a misdoing through documenting (*write*) the fix.

Maybe pop culture is circulating an incorrectly worded idiom to make a point?

Maybe these are actually two different idioms with two distinct meanings, such as *righting a wrong* to rectify it and *writing a wrong* to accuse someone?

Comment: I personally have never encountered "writing a wrong", and if I did I would assume it was a deliberate play on words. So far as I know; the only widespread idiom is "righting wrongs".

Comment: As I suspected, this [Google nGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=right+a+wrong%2C+righting+wrongs%2C+write+a+wrong%2C+writing+wrongs&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cright%20a%20wrong%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crighting%20wrongs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwrite%20a%20wrong%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwriting%20wrongs%3B%2Cc0) demonstrates that *writing wrongs* is virtually unknown (compared with *righting wrongs*), except, as I said, for deliberate wordplay.

Comment: "Writing wrongs" is not an idiom, it's just a spelling error.  "Righting wrongs" is not really an idiom either, i think, is it?

Comment: And a deeper search of the COCA Corpus also establishes that the idiom is *righting wrongs* or *right a wrong*, not *writing wrongs* or *write a wrong*. COCA makes it hard to link to particular results, but here's a couple screenshots of the results of comparing [*righting wrongs* vs *writing wrongs* and *right a wrong* vs *write a wrong*](https://imgur.com/a/yOMsr) (and it turns out this last doesn't appear even once in the entire corpus).

Comment: Ask yourself if _two wrongs don't make a right_, or don't they make _a write_?

Comment: Maybe these couple books with the title ["Writing the Wrongs"](http://www.amazon.com/Writing-Wrongs-Commentators-Reformation-Historical/dp/0195137361) and ["Writing My Wrongs"](http://www.amazon.com/Writing-My-Wrongs-Redemption-American/dp/B01C3BD2JE) are using a play on words based on "Righting wrongs"?  I also see a Yahoo Q&A about ["Writing the wrongs"](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110706100344AAWt8O7) which must also be an unintentional misspelling?  This sort of misuse (intentional or not) has lead me to posting the question on this site.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To right a wrong would be to correct it.
To write a wrong would be to make a written record of it.

I've not seen the phrase "write a wrong" written down before but it would make a rather nice pun.